# Access PHP-FPM's /status page manually (bypass Apache)

Tags: php-fpm, fcgi

There is a [PHP5.3.3 bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52674) that won't allow me to view php-fpm's /status page via Apache2.
Is there a way to manually access this data?  I cannot upgrade the box (Ubuntu 10.10, php5.3.4 not supported).

I've tried connecting using the technique here: http://inode.co.nz/testing-a-fastcgi-service, but no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to load the /status page, you must have certain environment variables set, specifically: `SCRIPT_NAME`, `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, `QUERY_STRING`, and `REQUEST_METHOD`. You do not need `DOCUMENT_ROOT` (even for a normal request).

Under the correct pool (it is not a global setting) of your php-fpm config set (or uncomment):

```
pm.status_path = /status
```

Then run (replacing PORT):

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/status \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status \
QUERY_STRING= \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:PORT
```

Sample Output:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.9
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/plain

pool:                 web1
process manager:      dynamic
start time:           28/Jan/2012:20:49:44 -0500
start since:          5955
accepted conn:        41
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     128
idle processes:       1
active processes:     1
total processes:      2
max active processes: 1
max children reached: 0
```

Note: the results are pool specific.

Tested on a RHEL/CentOS 6 system with PHP v5.3.9.

(Side point of mention for people using CentOS - the package that provides `cgi-fcgi` is named `fcgi` and available from EPEL)

As an aside, the same can be achieved with ping:

Set: `ping.path = /ping` (php-fpm config)

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/ping\
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/ping\
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:PORT
```

Or for a regular PHP file (you have to use the full path, QUERY_STRING is optional):

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/test.php \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/var/www/path/to/test.php \
QUERY_STRING= \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:PORT
```

Comment: IT WORKED!!!  I had tried every iteration of (REQUEST_METHOD and DOCUMENT_ROOT and (SCRIPT_NAME or SCRIPT_FILENAME)).  Thank you incredibly.

Answer (score 0):

On newer ubuntu (e.g. 20), install the libfcgi-bin package `apt install libfcgi-bin` to get the cgi-fcgi command.